# ArcGIS Pro - Split Line Feature Layer

Tags: gis, geospatial, arcgis, arcpy

I am working with an old line feature layer of a road network. I want to update the layer by splitting the roads by intersection. For example, if a road crosses multiple intersections, at each intersection the road would be split creating a new line feature. For one road crossing two intersections would be split into 3 separate features (roads). Is there a tool to do this automatically? Rather than by manually splitting?

The purpose of this is to be able to analyze the roads on a block-by-block basis.

I looked at the Geoprocessing tools and I could not find a tool. I heard the Arc Hydro tool may work.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [`arcpy.management.FeatureToLine`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-line.htm) (*Feature To Line*).

[image]
[image]

Here is a Python example using the tool:

```py
import arcpy, arcpy.management

roads = r"d:\temp\test\roads.shp"

segmented_roads = r"d:\temp\test\segmented_roads.shp"

arcpy.management.FeatureToLine(roads, segmented_roads)
```

---

However, the tool above is not available in the Basic licence of ArcGIS Pro. You may also want to look into an open-source solution such as using the [*Split with lines*](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines) tool from QGIS:

[image]